# Link Routing Table To Existing VNet, but VNet does not exist

Tags: azure, networking, cloud

I'm having an issue in Azure, I currently created a resource group and a VNet of the same name. I have a server and a virtual appliance deployed there. I wanted to setup IP forwarding and designate my virtual appliance as the next hop in the route. The problem is when I try to designate which route table to use it's giving me an error that it doesn't exist. I was following this guide:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-udr-how-to/

When I run Get-AzureVNetConfig the xml file doesn't have my resource group listed with its associated VNet. I am trying to figure out if this is an issue with the Classic vs ARM portal and if I just need to start over and verify the VNet exists in the config before I proceed or if there's another way to get this working.

It's also frustrating that there's not an easy way to switch your machines VNet without deleting the machine and reconnecting the disc on the new VNet. If anyone has any ideas it's greatly appreciated. Also if anyone has any recommendations on books or resources for understanding networking in Azure that would be excellent as well.

Comment: Did you set up your VNet using the classic or ARM portal?

Comment: I believe it was ARM? I take it the best way out is to create a box using classic as well as a VNet. I am not up to speed on the rapid deployment model that ARM offers through powershell.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and blew away the old servers and made sure I kept everything consistent on the new ARM. Mainly making sure my VNet exists and I can add my servers to it before going any further. I think everything should work from here on out. So I guess my last question is are there any good books covering cloud networking or should I just start reading the CCNA books from Wendell Odom?